# Adobe Captivate -- no links or clickboxes allowed on master pages -- what alternative?

Tags: adobe, adobe-captivate

It seems to be a well-worn truth in Captivate (I'm using v5) that no clickboxes or links are allowed on master pages, and that the only solution is to put them on each page.

I have 6 files with a total of 200 or more pages - I don't want to be pasting links laboriously to every page.

Is there a more efficient way to do that, a way around the "no clickboxes or links allowed on master pages" problem?

Answer (score 0):

Answer available here:

http://forums.adobe.com/message/4078176#4078176

Answer (score 0):

I don't this will work for click-boxes (at least not if you need to pause to give the user a chance to click them). But for links and for graphical elements, and for most any other sort of element, you simply add it to the first slide upon which it should appear, right-click it, and choose "display for rest of project."